# Another TinyMCE and Asp.Net UpdatePanel error (Permission denied)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, tinymce, updatepanel

I have a problem with tinymce and an UpdatePanel, I'm posting this because none of the other solutions have worked for me.

This is my code:

```
function pageLoad() {

        console.log("pageLoad called");
        tinyMCE.init({
            theme: "advanced",
            plugins: "preview,paste",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
            theme_advanced_buttons1: "undo,redo,|,bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,forecolor,backcolor",
            theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,link,unlink,|,removeformat,cleanup,preview",
            theme_advanced_buttons3: ""
        });

        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_beginRequest(function (sender, args) {
            var inst = tinyMCE.getInstanceById('<%= txtContenidoCorreo.ClientID %>');
            if (typeof inst !== 'undefined' && inst !== null) {
                console.log('removing');
                //tinyMCE.triggerSave();
                //tinyMCE.execCommand('mceFocus', false, '<%= txtContenidoCorreo.ClientID %>');
                tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, '<%= txtContenidoCorreo.ClientID %>');
                console.log('removed');
            }

        });

        prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, args) {
            var inst = tinyMCE.getInstanceById('<%= txtContenidoCorreo.ClientID %>');
            if (!inst) {
                console.log('initializing');
                tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, '<%= txtContenidoCorreo.ClientID %>');
                console.log('initialized');
            }
        });
    }
```

After a couple of asynchronous requests I get this error in IE9 and IE10:

> SCRIPT70: Permission Denied.

The exact line where this error happens is:

```
result = this.bodyElement || this.getDoc().body;
```

This is the stack trace:

> getBody@/JavaScript/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js:14548:11
>
> getContent@/JavaScript/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js:14458:30
>
> save@/JavaScript/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js:14377:4
>
> {anonymous}()@(/JavaScript/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js:13466:17)
>
> dispatch@/JavaScript/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js:562:4
>
> eventHandler@/JavaScript/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js:14905:5
>
> executeHandlers@/JavaScript/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js:4731:6

I'm using Tinymce 3.5.8

Comment: can you fiddle with the line and find out if this.bodyElement and this.getDoc() are defined?

Comment: this.bodyElement is undefined, this.getDoc() is the one that throws the error

Comment: ok, can you verify that both (the main window and the tinymce) iframe have the same domain?

Comment: Yes, they have the same domain

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Comment: no, I'm using ckeditor instead and it's working fine.